# ngClass style with variable in key

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ng-class

I hope someone can help me out.
I am using angular v1.3.14 and I try to add a scope variable in a key of a ng-class map.

example

```
        <b class="fixedClass" ng-class="{'classOne'       : x === 'foo',
                                         'classTwo-%(y)%' : x === 'bar'}">
            %(z)%
        </b>
```

is there any way to do something like this or is there a way around ?

Comment: what are you trying to do..  are you trying to assign a dynamic class name

Comment: I am creating a directive where I deliver %(y)% [in this case]

Comment: then I think a better choice will to use a variable as the class name like `ng-class="dynaClass"` then use watch on `x` to update the value of `dynaclass`

Comment: somehow it work's now with the code-usage above. I am suprised myself.

Comment: are you saying your code is working now?

Comment: It is by some miracle. Yesterday he wasn't able to resolve the %(y)% - but now somehow it does. I have no clue what changes lead to this - everything seems as before

Comment: @Kris there must be console error..what is `%` wrapper in `%(y)%`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
angular.module('App',[])
.controller('AppController',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.y = 10;
    $scope.val = 'bar';

    var fixedClass = "fixedClass ";

    $scope.getCSSClass = function(){
      if($scope.val === 'foo'){
        return fixedClass + 'classOne';
      } else {
        return fixedClass + 'classTwo-(' +$scope.y+ ')';
      }
    };
}])
```

In Html

```
<body ng-controller="AppController">
  <b ng-class="getCSSClass()">hello</b>
</body>
```

Here is the [working](http://jsbin.com/hobabumepa/1/) code

Comment: That would work, but `isActive()` is IMHO bad name.  Better name would be something like `getCssClass()`

Comment: Yea using a controller would work here - thanks for noting it here with a sample. I would still prefer a solution without using an extra controller for this problem :)

Comment: your example should work too :), But try to keep your template clean from logics if you can. Controller is a good place for that kind of stuff. Adding one  more controller will not slow down your code.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your requirement, it appears you are mixing static class names with dynamic class names. Preferred approach would be

`ng-class="['fixedClass',' fixedClass2',getDynamicStyle()]"`

`getDynamicStyle` is exposed in scope to return the value of dynamic class name. You may add any number of dynamic styles.